# Does iOS support a fully ISO regional format?

Tags: ios, settings, development

I need a regional format that satisfies all of the following.

1. Metric system
2. Monday week start
3. all numbers YMD date format in English
4. dot for decimal separator

The measurement system affects Siri etc. and getting an answer in miles is as good as gibberish to me.

The week start affects Screen Time etc., as I would like Saturday and Sunday to be grouped together with the preceding weekdays. I would also like to avoid potential scheduling or date mix-ups as I use Monday start.

The YMD date format allows me to share documents, screenshots etc. with dates that do not cause potential misunderstandings to other people.

The dot separator is not necessary, but the decimal separator cannot be comma while the thousand separator is dot. Again, this is to avoid confusion as most English speakers and especially those I work with only recognize dot as the decimal separator and comma as the thousand separator.

On MacOS all of these can be configured, but they cannot on iOS, at least not for the scenarios described above.